# Parallel transport along a curve using the general linear group?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose a manifold $M$ with 4 dimensions. I define a frame bundle at every point of this manifold whose structure is the general linear group. The following matrix-valued-field keeps track of a general linear element at every point of the manifold:

$$
\mathbf{G}(x,y,z,t)=\pmatrix{a_{00}(x,y,z,t)& \dots & a_{03}(x,y,z,t)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{30}(x,y,z,t) & \dots & a_{33}(x,y,z,t)
}
$$

where $\mathbf{G}(x,y,z,t)$ defines a general linear element at every point of the manifold.

It also turns out that $\mathbf{G}(x,y,z,t)$ transforms according to the general linear group. Therefore, I can create a series of transformations by 'chaining' general linear transformations:

$$
\mathbf{G}(x',y',z',t')= \mathbf{G}_0 \mathbf{G}_1\mathbf{G}_2 \mathbf{G}_3...\mathbf{G}(x,y,z,t)
$$

It seems to me like this chaining can be used to parallel transport $\mathbf{G}(x,y,z,t)$ along a curve on the manifold.

I assume those transformations must be infinitesimal.

It is possible to define parallel transport using chaining of group elements in such a manner, or similar manner?